# LargeInteger's equivalent of BigInteger's testBit?

Tags: java, biginteger, jscience

Does [`LargeInteger`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html) have an equivalent to [`BigInteger`'s `testBit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#testBit%28int%29)?

If not, how can `testBit` be performed on a `LargeInteger`?

I don't yet have the necessary skills to reproduce `((this & (1<<n)) != 0)`.

---

I tried making a method by just copying & pasting the above code referenced from the docs:

```
static boolean testBit(int n){
    return ((this & (1<<n)) != 0);
}
```

However, the compiler reports:

```
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
    return ((this & (1<<n)) != 0);
             ^
error: bad operand types for binary operator '&'
    return ((this & (1<<n)) != 0);
                  ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with given the API:

```
static boolean testBit(LargeInteger i, int n) {
    return i.shiftRight(n).isOdd();
}
```

`n` is the position of the bit to be tested.

I assume you put this method in some utility class.

### Explanation

Normally, you would do `num & (1 << pos)` to extract the bit at `pos` position:

```
???????x?????
0000000100000
-------------
0000000x00000
```

If the whole thing is 0 then `x` is 0; otherwise, `x` is 1.

---

In the method above, I do `num >> pos`:

```
???????x?????
-------------
????????????x
```

We know that a binary number is odd when its least significant bit is 1, and it is even when its least significant bit is 0.

So if the number after right-shifting is odd, we know the bit is 1; if even, we know the bit is 0.

Comment: @Gracchus: It is correct. `i & (1 << n)` leaves only the bit at position `n` on, and `(i >> n) & 1` does the same thing (extract the bit at position `n`). A binary number whose least significant digit is 1 means the number is odd. That explains the part I test for odd number (without AND with 1).

Comment: @Gracchus: Can you isolate the error? I also want to know why it doesn't work for you.