# LargeInteger's equivalent of BigInteger's and?

Tags: java, binary, biginteger, jscience

[`LargeInteger`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html) doesn't appear to have an equivalent function to [`BigInteger`'s `and`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#and%28java.math.BigInteger%29).

Since `and(BigInteger val)` "`Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this & val). (This method returns a negative BigInteger if and only if this and val are both negative.)`", I tried to follow [this great answer on reproducing `testBit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287910/1382306) with

```
static LargeInteger and(LargeInteger i, LargeInteger j) {
    return i & j;
}
```

but the compiler reports

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '&'
    return i & j;
             ^
```

How can `BigInteger`'s `and` be reproduced to be used on `LargeInteger`?

Comment: Are you really sure that LargeInteger is what you want? It seems like you do a lot of bit level stuff that is not supported there?

Comment: @Ingo Thank you for looking Ingo!  No, I'm not at all, but the performance of ed25519 is unbearable with `BigInteger`, and I've found that this could be an easy bottleneck to fix by substituting with `LargeInteger`.  If, after the code is converted, it works correctly and faster, I will fork and upload the alterations.  If `and` is impossible, I can fall back by converting a `BigInteger` to `LargeInteger`, but I'd prefer to remove `BigInteger` completely.  https://github.com/k3d3/ed25519-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.jscience.mathematics.number.LargeInteger` does not seem to have a similar bit-wise function `and` (if I have sougth the right class & version).

```
static LargeInteger and(LargeInteger lhs, LargeInteger rhs) {
     long l = lhs.longValue(); // Low order bits
     long r = rhs.longValue();
     long lo = l & r;

     LargeInteger hi = LargeInteger.ZERO;
     if (lhs.bitLength() > 64 && rhs.bitLength() > 64) {
         hi = and(lhs.shiftRight(64), rhs.shiftRight(64)).shiftLeft(64);
     }
     return hi.plus(lo);
}
```

Mind, that for a bitwise `or` the condition needs `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the documentation, there are methods for converting LargeIntegers into byte arrays, and also to create a LargeInteger from byte arrays. Hence, you can do the following:

```
convert operands to byte arrays
combine the individual bytes with the operator you want (&, |, ^)
convert resulting byte array back to LargeInteger
```

Now, correct me if I am wrong, but the original python code seems to only do `n & 1`.
Since you have even() and odd() methods, why not use them? The following identity holds:

```
 large & 1 = large.odd() ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Thank you Ingo!  You are correct, I have no idea since I have no experience with binary.  I'm merely trying to substitute `BigInteger` with `LargeInteger` for ed25519.  I also have no experience with cryptography, so I'm holding my breath, hoping this works.

Comment: @Gracchus, see if I am correct that you only need (&1), and not (x&y) in general.

Comment: `convert operands to byte arrays` I can't find such method though (only find the one to convert from byte to LargeInteger). What is the method that you found?

Comment: @nhahtdh http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html#toByteArray%28byte[],%20int%29